# How to use function that return value inside a template? Vuex, Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm using a template to get data of a json file, I use "v-for" to print all data, for example:

```
template: /*html*/
    ` 
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <template v-for="item of actividades">
            <ul>
                <li>{{ item.date }}</li>
            <ul>
        </template>
    </div>
    `,
```

But I need use functions, year() to modificate this information and return and result, for example:

```
   template: /*html*/
    ` 
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <template v-for="item of actividades">
            <ul>
                <li>{{ year(item.date) }}</li>
            <ul>
        </template>
    </div>
    `,
```

**The value {{ item.date }} print "2021-01-20" but I hope print "2021" using the function  {{ year(item.date) }}**

Code function year() using javascript:

```
year(date){
            return String(date).substr(0, 4);
        }
```

I tried use that code but is not working, appear this error:
[image: this image show error]

That's my javascript code:

```
//VueEx
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        actividades: [],
        programas: [],
        year: ""
    },
    mutations: {
        llamarJsonMutation(state, llamarJsonAction){
            state.actividades = llamarJsonAction.Nueva_estructura_proveedor;
            state.programas = llamarJsonAction.BD_programas;
        },
        yearFunction(state, date){
            state.year = String(date).substr(8, 2);
            return state.year;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        llamarJson: async function({ commit }){
            const data = await fetch('calendario-2021-prueba.json');
            const dataJson = await data.json();
            commit('llamarJsonMutation', dataJson);
        }
    }
});

//Vue
new Vue({
    el: '#caja-vue',
    store: store,
    created() {
        this.$store.dispatch('llamarJson');
      }
});
```

Comment: How is it not "working"? What's the expected outcome? What actually happened?

Comment: Appear loop error.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Your first part of the question of about a component which is looping data and needs a `year` function, your second part of about a vuex store, but you don't show how these two interact. Really hard to understand your problem.

Comment: Please, excuse me, I updated the post and upload a image where you can see the error.

Comment: I'm not sure it's allow to use a function in `{{}}`. Anyway I think you could deal with the data in function llamarJsonMutation before where  it assigned to actividades.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside a template you can use functions defined as `methods` or `computed`. Technically, you can also use `data` to pass a function to the template, but I wouldn't recommend it. Not that it wouldn't work, but Vue makes anything declared in `data` reactive and there's no point in making a function (which is basically a constant) reactive. So, in your case:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    actividades: [
      { date: '2021-01-20' },
      { date: '2020-01-20' },
      { date: '2019-01-20' },
      { date: '2018-01-20' },
      { date: '2017-01-20' }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    year(date) { return date.substring(0, 4); }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, key) in actividades" :key="key">
        {{ year(item.date) }}
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If, for some reason, you want to pass `year` as `computed`:

```
computed: {
  year() { return date => date.substring(0, 4); }
}
```

But it's a convoluted construct (a getter function returning an inner arrow function) and this complexity doesn't serve any purpose. I'd recommend you use a `method` in your case, since it's the most straight-forward (easy to read/understand).

---

If you're importing the `year` function from another file:

```
import { year } from '../helpers'; // random example, replace with your import

// inside component's methods:

methods: {
  year, // this provides `year` imported function to the template, as `year`
        // it is equivalent to `year: year,`
  // other methods here
}
```

---

Side notes:

- there is no point in iterating through `<template>` tags which contain `<ul>`'s. You can place the v-for directly on the `<ul>` and lose the `<template>` (You should only use `<template>` when you want to apply some logic - i.e: a `v-if` - to a bunch of elements without actually wrapping them into a DOM wrapper; another use-case is when you want its children to be direct descendants of the its parent: for `<ul>`/`<li>` or `<tbody>`/`<tr>` relations, where you can't have intermediary wrappers between them). In your case, placing the `v-for` on the `<ul>` produces the exact same result with less code.
- you should always `key` your `v-for`'s: `<ul v-for="(item, key) in actividades" :key="key">`. Keys help Vue [maintain the state](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State) of list elements, keep track of animations and update them correctly

Comment: your explication is awesome, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to work with the Vuex store. And using mutation inside the template syntax.

Not sure if we can call mutation directly via HTML as the way you are doing. In the past when I tried to call a mutation, I would either:

- Create an action which would commit that mutation and call that action wrapped inside a method through Vue, something like this:[look for a method printSampleLog() that I defined here](https://jsfiddle.net/abhijeetjain/jwyug97n/3/)

```js
Vue.component('followers', {
  template: '<div>Followers: {{ computedFollowers }} {{printSampleLog()}}</div>',
  data() {
    return { followers: 0 }
  },
  created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('getFollowers').then(res => {
        this.followers = res.data.followers
    })
  },
  computed: {
    computedFollowers: function () {
        return this.followers
    }
  },
  methods:{
  printSampleLog(){
  this.$store.dispatch('sampleAction').then(res => {
        this.followers = res.data.followers
    })
  }
  }
});

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  actions: {
    getFollowers() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/octocat')
          .then(response => resolve(response))
          .catch(err => reject(error))
      });
    },
    sampleAction(context){
    context.commit('sampleMutation');
    }
  },
  mutations: {
  sampleMutation(){
    console.log("sample mutation")
  }
  }
})

const app = new Vue({
    store,
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <followers></followers>
</div>
```

- Else create method w/o action in your Vue component committing the mutation directly, using this.$store.commit()

PS: Would recommend creating action around the mutation first, as it is a much cleaner approach.

Comment: @luis, let me know if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: It's perfectly safe to call `mutation`s or `action`s from anywhere. The only difference is that `action`s are `async` (and return a promise - they have a `.then()`) and `mutation`s are synchronous.